# qsort a dynamic array

Tags: c, vector, qsort

I am using a dynamic array I found online whose header file looks like this:

```
    typedef struct {
    int size;      // slots used so far
    int capacity;  // total available slots
    void **data;     // array of data we're storing
    } Vector;

    void vector_init(Vector *vector);

    void vector_append(Vector *vector, void* value);

    void* vector_get(Vector *vector, int index);

    void vector_set(Vector *vector, int index, void* value);

    void vector_double_capacity_if_full(Vector *vector);

    void vector_free(Vector *vector);
```

I have another struct that looks this:

```
typedef struct _item{
    char name[MaxNameSize];
    float price;
} Item;
```

I have created a vector using

```
Vector vector;
vector_init(&vector);
```

and added a number of Items to it using

```
vector_append(&vector, item);
```

multiple times where item are of type Item. I now want to sort my dynamic array by Item price. I have tried this which doesn't work

```
qsort(vector.data, vector.size, sizeof(Item*), compare);
```

My compare function is

```
int compare(const void* a, const void* b){
Item* first = (Item*)a;
Item* second = (Item*)b;
    return first.price - second.price;
}
```

Any ideas of where I am going wrong? I think it may be the arguments I am putting into the qsort. Right now it seems to just skip over the qsort.

Comment: The addresses you're receiving in `compare` are offset addresses into the `data` pointer array. I.e. The actual type is `void**` passed as `void*`.
Therefore, you're missing a level of indirection. That your syntax is wrong regardless (ex: it would be `first->price`, not `first.price`) doesn't help, but even if that were right, the premise you currently have, that `Item*` are passed as `void*` is wrong.

Comment: Sorry I've fixed putting -> now but you're right that wasn't the only problem. I kind of understand what you're saying about void* and void**. What do I do to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your declaration of `Vector` includes a pointer-to-pointer-to-void for the data bed (`void**`). Without seeing the rest of your code, I must assume this means you're managing a vector of pointers, where each pointer refers to a distinct object by-address. The addresses you're receiving in `compare` are offset addresses into the `data` pointer array. I.e. The actual type is `void**` passed as `void*`.

Therefore, you're missing a level of indirection. That your syntax is wrong regardless (ex: it would be `first->price`, not `first.price`) doesn't help, but even if that were right, the premise you currently have, that `Item*` are passed as `void*` is wrong.

Your comparator should be like this, assuming the rest of your code is correct:

```
int compare(const void* a, const void *b)
{
    const Item * first = *(const void * const *)a;
    const Item * second = *(const void * const *)b;
    return first->price < second->price ? -1 : second->price < first->price;
}
```

Again, this is making pretty big assumptions about the code you're *not* providing, and there are no guarantees this will work unless that code is solid and fulfills the assumptions made above. But if you're managing this vector as described above, it should work.

I've also taken liberty to fix the comparison itself. Subtracting values may appear to work for integral types, but the wheels quickly fall off for floating point when converted to a final `int` result, or even integral types if you introduce underflow potential. For a trivial example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", (int)(1.1f - 1.0f)); // wrong
    printf("%d\n", (1.1f < 1.0f ? -1 : 1.0f < 1.1f)); // better
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
0
1
```

It can also end up in implementation-defined land if converting a larger-integral-type value (suppose you were subtracting `long long` and the result were *less* than `INT_MIN`). Sticking with the form I showed avoids that pitfall

```
if (a < b) return -1;
return (b < a); // will be 1 or 0, depending on whether b < a or not.
```

Thus the comparator always returns -1, 0, or 1 and conforms to the requirements of `qsort` whilst doing so and avoiding the inaccuracy of floating point to `int` conversion or potential underflow/overflow.

Best of luck.

Comment: Plus one for pointing that subtraction is wrong. Problems (overflow) can happen to integers as well.

Answer (score 1):

edit: as WhozCraig pointed out, data is an array of pointers. Thus:

first and second are pointers to a pointer, thus you must get the reference to the pointer to an Item and then use `->` to refer to the fields of the struct. In all, it should look like:

```
Item* first = *(Item**)a;
Item* second = *(Item**)b;
return first->price - second->price;
```

Comment: Yes I've fixed this but this wasn't the main problem as someone has said above.